# In and Out Paramater Confusion in stored procedure of Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am new to stored procedures in Mysql and working on some basic stored procedures to fetch data from a single table based on multiple conditions. I am a  bit confused in IN and OUT parameters which stored procedure accept and returns respectively.

Below is the select statement for which I am creating a stored procedure.

```
select name from item where id in
(select item_id from stock where created_by_id != processor_id and processor_id in 
(select id from users where type ='Manager'));
```

name is a column in item table from which I want to get data based on a condition. when I am running a above query..it returns me correct output as below.

```
#name
'Samsung'
'Pant'
```

but when I am running the same statement using a stored procedure as below.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_ItemName3;
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ItemName3 (IN userType varchar(255), OUT Name varchar(255))
       BEGIN
       select name from item where id in
       (select item_id from stock where created_by_id != processor_id and processor_id in 
       (select id from users where type = userType));
       END
       //

Call sp_ItemName3('Manager',@Name);
```

After calling the stored procedure it returns me two NULL rows. what is the reason? mysql workbench is not returning any error/exception.

Correct me..if I am doing something wrong...!!

Comment: You must ```SELECT field INTO outParameter FROM table ...```. So here ```SELECT name INTO Name FROM item WHERE ...``` to assign the result to your @Name variable

Comment: Well that's a terrible query. See about joins. :-(

Comment: @OlivierDepriester thanks..i have done that but when i calling stored procedure it give me strange error.. **Result consisted more than one row**

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you..Its good to use joins..but my preference here is subqueries

Comment: A preference based on what? Aesthetics?

Comment: Your query as you stated gives back **2 rows** your out variable is varchar(255) so it expects only **1 column** and **1 row**  so Concat or GROUPO:Cocat the results

Comment: @nbk thank you for the suggestion...but still i am getting error..is am i doing something wronng here `
       select  group_concat(name) as `itemname` INTO Name from item where id in
       (select item_id from stock where created_by_id != processor_id and processor_id in 
       (select id from users where type = userType)) group by id;
`

Comment: make a dbfiddel with your tables and data and i see what could be the problem.

Comment: @Strawberry this platform is to help struggling people..sadly i am still student and i am learning new things..Hope you will get my point..everyone is student at some point of there life and No one learns everything in one single shot

Comment: Sure. Hence my question. I find your dismissal of my suggestion odd, and it undermines your argument

Comment: @nbk it working now..i have tried with join and it working perfect.. i dont know whats the reason..may be its a problem of mysql version/suquery issue..thank you so much

Comment: @Strawberry hey..i tried with join and it works for me..i didn't know the reason..sorry but i dont dismissal your suggestion..in past struggled with joins so thats the reason..anyway thank you so much

Comment: Incidentally, while it's obviously fine for teaching yourself about procedures, there's nothing here that requires one. A simple query would be more appropriate in this instance.